# Why is the virtualbox package in contrib and not in the main Debian repository?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

[The VirutalBox's website says that](https://www.virtualbox.org/):

> VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product
> for enterprise as well as home use. Not only is VirtualBox an
> extremely feature rich, high performance product for enterprise
> customers, it is also the only professional solution that is freely
> available as Open Source Software under the terms of the **GNU General**
> **Public License (GPL) version 2**. See "About VirtualBox" for an
> introduction.

So why is the `virtualbox` package in `contrib` and not in the `main` Debian repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained in [the package’s `debian/copyright` file](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-virtualbox-team/virtualbox/-/blob/master/debian/copyright), which is installed as `/usr/share/doc/virtualbox/copyright`:

> This package is not part of the Debian operating system.
> It is in the "contrib" area of the Debian archive because it requires a
> non-free compiler (Open Watcom) to build the BIOS.
> Upstream provides pre-built BIOS images which is used instead.

This fails the following requirement on [packages in main](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#the-main-archive-area):

> the packages in *main* must not require or recommend a package outside of *main* for compilation or execution

Since the package’s license meets the DFSG, it is distributed in contrib.